# Java: Storing an array before sorting

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get this beginning part of my program to work the way I want it to before I move on and it's driving me crazy. In an attempt to receive 5 inputs for book title, author, page count, I'm receiving 6 for book title, 5 for author, and 5 for pg count. My end result is to just have each array with 5 inputs for each stored so I can organize them based on what the user requests. Do you see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
     String[] titleChoice = new String[5];
     String title = "", titleString = "";
     String[] authorChoice = new String[5];
     String author = "", authorString = "";
     String[] pageChoice = new String[5];
     String page = "", pageString = "";
     String currentTitle;

     String formatEntry;

     int x = 0;
     int numEntered;

     int highestTitle = titleChoice.length - 1;
     int highestAuthor = authorChoice.length - 1;
     int highestPage = pageChoice.length - 1;

     final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 5;

     boolean notQuit = false;

           Arrays.fill(titleChoice, "zzzzzzzzzzz");
           Arrays.fill(authorChoice, "zzzzzzzzzzz");
           Arrays.fill(pageChoice, "zzzzzzzzzzz");

     do
        {
        currentTitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the title of a book, or zzz to 
                 quit:");

        if(!currentTitle.equals("zzz"))
           {
           titleChoice[x] = currentTitle;
           authorChoice[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter "
                 + titleChoice[x] + "'s author's last name: ");

           pageChoice[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter "
                 + titleChoice[x] + "'s page count: ");

           x = x + 1;
           }
           else
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have elected to quit the program.    
          Goodbye.);
        }
     while(!currentTitle.equals("zzz"));
```

Receiving an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for titleChoice[x] = currentTitle; as well. Not really sure how to remedy this.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm receiving 6 for book title"? The array only has 5 entries.

Comment: Yes exactly! the array is set up for only 5, but it asks again for another book title and I have no idea

Comment: I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for the following: titleChoice[x] = currentTitle;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string in the `else` statement isn't closed, but besides that unless the user enters "zzz" on the 5th input the loop increments x and tries again with a nonexistent index. As suggested above `while(!currentTitle.equals("zzz") && x < 5)` should work because is limits the index to a number within the Array bounds (0 - 4).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the program to stop asking for more than 5 titles add a further condition to the while:

```
while(!currentTitle.equals("zzz") && x < 5);
```

otherwise it will keep asking until you enter zzz.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your 6th book title is "zzz".  They are entering a 6th title to quit but then you aren't running the section of code that generates an author and page so those both still have 5 entries.

Comment: No, it's not listed as "zzz" it just asks again for another book title... a sixth time

Comment: Ah...I would guess that's because you are using a do-while loop instead of a regular while loop.

Comment: In an attempt to use just a while loop, the Input Panes went blank...like I said it's driving me crazy!